# Machine learning: Which algorithm is used to identify relevant features in a training set?

Tags: machine-learning

I've got a problem where I've potentially got a **huge number of features**. Essentially a mountain of data points (for discussion let's say it's in the millions of features). I **don't know what data points are useful** and what are irrelevant to a given outcome (I guess 1% are relevant and 99% are irrelevant).

I do have the data points and the final outcome (a binary result). I'm interested in **reducing the feature set** so that I can identify the most useful set of data points to collect to train future classification algorithms.

My current data set is huge, and I can't generate as many training examples with the mountain of data as I could if I were to identify the relevant features, cut down how many data points I collect, and increase the number of training examples. I expect that I would get better classifiers with more training examples given fewer feature data points (while maintaining the relevant ones).

- What machine learning algorithms should I focus on to, first,
  identify the features that are relevant to the outcome?

From some reading I've done it seems like *SVM* provides weighting per feature that I can use to identify the most highly scored features. *Can anyone confirm this? Expand on the explanation? Or should I be thinking along another line?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feature weights in a linear model (logistic regression, naive Bayes, etc) can be thought of as measures of importance, provided your features are all on the same scale.

Your model can be combined with a regularizer for learning that penalises certain kinds of feature vectors (essentially folding feature selection into the classification problem). L1 regularized logistic regression sounds like it would be perfect for what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use PCA or Maximum entropy algorithm in order to reduce the data set...

Answer (score 1):

You can go for Chi-Square tests or Entropy depending on your data type. Supervized discretization highly reduces the size of your data in a smart way (take a look into Recursive Minimal Entropy Partitioning algorithm proposed by Fayyad & Irani).

Answer (score 0):

If you work in R, the SIS package has a function that will do this for you.

If you want to do things the hard way, what you want to do is feature screening, a massive preliminary dimension reduction before you do feature selection and model selection from a sane-sized set of features.  Figuring out what is the sane-size can be tricky, and I don't have a magic answer for that, but you can prioritize what order you'd want to include the features by 
1) for each feature, split the data in two groups by the binary response
2) find the Komogorov-Smirnov statistic comparing the two sets
The features with the highest KS statistic are most useful in modeling.

There's a paper "out there" titled "A selctive overview of feature screening for ultrahigh-dimensional data" by Liu, Zhong, and Li, I'm sure a free copy is floating around the web somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

4 years later I'm now halfway through a PhD in this field and I want to add that the definition of a feature is not always simple. In the case that your features are a single column in your dataset, the answers here apply quite well.

However, take the case of an image being processed by a convolutional neural network, for example, a feature is not one pixel of the input, rather it's much more conceptual than that. Here's a nice discussion for the case of images:

https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-3-deep-learning-and-convolutional-neural-networks-f40359318721